# Parole Stamp - under safeguard

Tags: visas

I worked on a cruise line with a C1D visa, however my contract was terminated and cut short and as a result I had to return home.

Upon returning home I received a parole stamp where it states I was under safeguard to the airport, I have gotten another job with another cruise line and I want to go back, however I am really scared that I get to the US and that this stamp would in some way deny my entry?

Does anyone have any clarity on the matter? I have tried to contact the embassy in my country but they have not gotten back to me and I am desperate as I am due to leave within the next two months!

Comment: I think you should ask to crew forum. Probably it is just to say you must exit country as quick as possible, you entered with D (crew), but than it was changed to C. "Parole" means "promise".

Comment: Sounds like this might be a fairly common situation. What did the cruise line that will be employing you say when you asked them?

Comment: Can you ask your new employer? You might need to reapply for a C1D visa

Comment: In US immigration terminology, "parole" means the immigration officer used their discretion to allow you entry to the US for a period of time without a visa. There is nothing negative about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paroled Stamp on passport in USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/182362/paroled-stamp-on-passport-in-usa)

Comment: I have jest seen your post and I am wondering how did you reenter US because I had the same, exact the same issue like you...
Could you please advise?