# Paroled stamp on passport in USA

Tags: indian-citizens, passport-stamps

I was working on a cruise ship, had travelled on a C1 D visa, I faced a back injury while working on the ship. My contract was shortened and I was sent back to India. The Passport has a PAROLED stamp with a pen written comment "to depart foreign", will I be able to travel back.

Comment: Was your visa cancelled?

Comment: Parole, in the immigration laws of the United States, generally refers to official permission to enter and remain temporarily in the United States, under the supervision of the U.S. Department of Homeland Security (DHS), without formal admission, and while remaining an applicant for admission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you were paroled and not admitted given that you have a valid visa. Generally, you should be able to travel back to the USA given that you meet all other entry conditions. A parole stamp indicates that you were allowed into the territory of the USA without being admitted. In the eyes of the law, you were always at the border awaiting a decision on admission. [Here](https://www.americanimmigrationcouncil.org/research/use-parole-under-immigration-law) you'll find a link which gives a more in-depth look into the legal meaning of parole in US immigration law.

Comment: Because the visa is surely linked to the contract. And since the contract has been shortned, the visa is likely invalid at some point

Comment: @NicolasFormichella ah yes, good point

Comment: @NicolasFormichella it's likely that the visa itself is not linked to the contract (if it were, it would have been cancelled) but rather that the conditions of admission included having an active contract.  This is a subtle distinction to be sure, but it fits with the fact that US visas are required to be valid only when the bearer arrives at the border.  It also allows people with a visa granted in connection with one employer to use the same visa after changing to another job (provided they are still eligible for admission in the same status).

Comment: I was on the cruise ship and had a valid C1 D Visa